# rxplot displaying wrong values

Tags: ros, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I publish a NavSatFix message on a topic. Using rostopic echo I can see that the longitude value is 13.475883. But when plotting the value with rxplot I get a value around 0.016.

I also observed similar behaviour for one of my own messages containing a set of float64.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29811/rxplot-displaying-wrong-values/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure its displaying the wrong value? matplotlib, which rxplot uses, sometimes readjusts the y-axis if the value range is small so that the Y-value is an offset from a fixed value.  The fixed value will be displayed on the axis as well.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2012-03-16**:
It seems you are right. Clicking on the line show the correct value. But I saw no fixed value displayed. But doing a configure I then saw the fixed value on the top. It was displayed but under the "menu" so you did not see it. This was very confusing.